# Using case expression in a view statement

Tags: sql, database, view, case

I have been searching for a long time how to do this, however due to the words involved when searching it is incredibly hard to find something close to what I am trying to find out!

How can I use the sql CASE expression within a create view?

Could someone please show me the correct syntax?

Below is how mine looks at the moment, but it is not working correctly.

```
create view vw_price as 
select vehicle.price
(case when price between 0 and 999 then ‘0-999’
    when price between 1000 and 1999 then ‘1000-1999’
    when price between 2000 and 2999 then ‘2000-2999’
    when price between 3000 and 3999 then ‘3000-3999’
    when price between 4000 and 4999 then ‘4000-4999’
    when price between 5000 and 5999 then ‘5000-5999’
    when price between 6000 and 6999 then ‘6000-6999’
    when price between 7000 and 7999 then ‘7000-7999’
    when price between 8000 and 8999 then ‘8000-8999’
    when price between 9000 and 9999 then ‘9000-9999’
end) as price_group from vehicle;
```

Comment: What does "not working correctly" mean here? Error message? Wrong data? Something else?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' . . . The error is the lack of a comma after `vehicle.price`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I know. I determined the OP needed to practice reading his or her syntax error messages. As a consultant, I spend a lot of time pretending to be a little bit ignorant, and asking the same question over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below syntax should work to create the required view. I think you are just missing a comma before the case statement.

```
USE [<<<database_name>>>]
GO

CREATE VIEW vw_price
AS
    select price,
        (case 
            when price between 0 and 999 then '0-999'
            when price between 1000 and 1999 then '1000-1999'
            when price between 2000 and 2999 then '2000-2999'
            when price between 3000 and 3999 then '3000-3999'
            when price between 4000 and 4999 then '4000-4999'
            when price between 5000 and 5999 then '5000-5999'
            when price between 6000 and 6999 then '6000-6999'
            when price between 7000 and 7999 then '7000-7999'
            when price between 8000 and 8999 then '8000-8999'
            when price between 9000 and 9999 then '9000-9999'
        end) "price_group" from vehicle;
GO
```